# Template for display fields in two columns instead of one columns in MVC 3 Razor

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, forms

The Details template of MVC 3 returned a view use `<fieldset>` to display elements that represent all fields in one column. But I need to show elements or fields of a model in two or more  columns. Is there any good template for this? what is your suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing specific about MVC here.  This is just plain old html and css.  I suggest getting a good book on HTML and CSS, and these sorts of things will be clear to you.

One of many many many ways you could do it:

http://www.gethifi.com/blog/html-forms-the-right-ways

Answer (score 0):

One option you have is using editor templates for MVC, which allow you to take control of the how html rendering for a model is generated. Here's a blog post with an example

[Using EditorTemplates in MVC 3](http://goo.gl/LP0oi)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is modifying the Scaffolding Template that generated that view.

Or other option could be doing that manually, checking the best way to "display" each of your models.

Comment: I actually want to add element manually, but need a good template to how arrange them